# Super User mug design

Tags: discussion

[image]

This week, [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) (pictured) and me received our [SU anniversary contest](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/07/announcing-the-winners-of-the-super-user-anniversary-contest/) prizes.

I really like most of the stuff I got. But **the Super User mug design sucks.**

[image]

1. It gets the [*Y U NO* guy](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/y-u-no-guy) meme [totally wrong](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3141051#3141051).
2. It's neither funny nor does it relate to the coffee mug (like the [Stack Overflow one](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/specials/products/mug)).
3. It misrepresents the content of Super User. SO's mug says: "It's about programming". But this one? Troubleshooting questions are the most boring we have IMO. There's a reason we're here instead of answering the family's phone calls.

To be honest, I'd have preferred a mug with just the Super User logo on the front (not shown), and nothing else on it, to this.

Comment: From the photo, stop holding the mug with that much pressure. Your thumb is pressing too hard

Comment: @random Thanks, I'll let slhck know.

Comment: Fix relative's computer once / Y U No stop calling?

Comment: @random I'd have suggested (if we *really* need this meme) `FIXED YOUR COMPUTER ONCE / Y U NO STOP CALLING` — but something else (or nothing at all) still would have been better...

Comment: I don't know anything about the meme, but "Fix computer once, family never stops calling" makes perfect sense for SU. "Fix computer, loved doing it" doesn't -- the point is "heh, we always get dragged into fixing family computer problems, right guys?"

Comment: [Relevant comic](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/computers).

Comment: **Clarification**: I won't return the mugs and I won't throw them away. I won them and *they're mine* and I'll use them (I am, right now, actually - perfectly suited for holding coffee). But the design really could be improved. I just want to get the powers that be to **consider doing another design iteration** for next year's winners, or for the mugs' introduction to the regular SE store.

Comment: I must admit the design wasn't too funny, but I'm glad they made one. It's quite big and I always love new mugs in my cupboard :) // @random   I had to decide between gripping tight to either a DSLR or a mug, so I decided to do both :P

Comment: If anyone was wondering, this is the original meme: http://i.qkme.me/z58.jpg

Comment: That incorrect use of the meme would be as irritating on a daily basis as an rj45 cable with the clip broken off

Comment: Interwebz Meme -- Y U NO FUNNY?

Answer (score 17):

Maybe next time the proposed swag art should be voted on here on meta, so that issues like this can be worked out *before* the swag arrives?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing just a few minutes ago. We could still do this, *if* there are plans for further promotions/prizes or adding them to the SE store. As I wrote in a comment, this topic is (while admittedly phrased poorly) intended to help improve iteration 2. Any plans?

Comment: Definitely agree with this. the entire idea behind SE is how the community runs it, and I think even our swag should be chosen by us.

Answer (score 8):

How about:

> There are 10 types of people in the world / and SU has something for both of them

Or a shortened version (I think "them both" is more awkward than "both of them", but it saves three more character spaces)

> There are 10 types of people / SU has something for them both

Comment: The only downside I see in this one is that it's quite long and has to wrap around / gets not proportional to the logo, would we go for a shorter version or put each part on two lines instead of one? Or is this intended to be printed along the middle with no image, because then two lines would make sense. The same problem could arise for your other suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

Or:

> The confluence of thousands of problems and millions of solutions: Some things are worth staying in your mother's basement for!