# Super User Swag is still wanted

Tags: discussion, support

Looking through the sidebar, I found [this old question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4146/super-user-mug-design) about the Super User mug. I'm wondering if there's any update from the team about making swag available for purchase any time soon? Or what kind of obstacles need to be squashed before we can get something?

Comment: They don't do swag at all anymore. If I can find this mug among the thousand others my wife collects I could send it to you :)

Comment: I still want swag to purchase... But thought I'd ask anyways

Comment: The SU mug is one of my most valued mugs, ahead even of my DailyWTF mug. Too bad it's too large for the coffee machine I have :-(

Comment: @Daniel I'll take it off your hands for you... (shifty eyes)

Comment: I love my SU mugs! They used to sell swag but the store got taken advantage of somehow and shut down because they were losing too much money. They might still have a few around, if you emailed Tim Post there's a small chance he might be able to hook you up...

Comment: I want to buy one too if its available! Anyone care to post a pic?

Comment: My wife almost wore my SU T-shirt the other day. I had to give her the hard word about it!

Comment: @MichaelFrank - Not the hard word! lol.... Next you will put her in the comfy chair! (Monty python).

Comment: I'm willing to get some too. If you can't sell them, why don't you just publish the pictures of them (not on the mug, I mean the design) with a CC license (non commercial) so that we can make ourselves SU Swag? (Through some online mug design website or etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swag is no longer available for purchase.

Swag is still given away - but as I'm not an employee (and probably even if I was) I can't tell you what criteria are used to decide who to give to and when.